# how to return a 204 response code in firebase hosting (node.js)

Tags: php, android, firebase, server, google-cloud-functions

Need some help. I am trying to access a file on firebase hosting with an android application, the application is downloading a .txt file and for verification reasons, before starting the download, it should check if the server is reachable, it needs a 204 response code (no content).

I can do it in PHP like so: (https://www.yourserver.com/return204.php):

```
<? php http_response_code(204); ?>
```

I found this link, but its looks very complicated: [Firebase HTTP Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http), compared to the PHP solution.
How can i do it in Firebase with Firebase Cloudfunctions or maybe simpler. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this...

```
res.status(204).end();
```

Here is the full function...

```
exports.MyFunction = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

   res.status(204).end();

});
```